# How to run ML within Abaqus material subroutine?

Tags: python, machine-learning, fortran, abaqus

I'm using Abaqus to run FEA simulations which include a material user subroutine (umat), written in Fortran 77 to define the material model. Currently I'm need to use data from the simulation (at run time) to train a machine learning algorithm (SVR or Random Forest Regression are yet to be chosen). Naturally most of the ML modules are in python, not in Fortran, so I have tried the following approach so far:

Within the UMAT I'm calling the python script via command line, the data is written in a csv file and used to train, the output is read back into the UMAT and the simulation continues.

It's working in toy models, although it turns out to be highly inefficient to keep calling the command line in the middle of the simulation and it's not feasible for real models.

The only alternative I could think was to code the ML algorithm in Fortran, in the subroutine itself, the problem is that it's not trivial to do it, SVR for instance requires the solution of an optimization problem using Lagrange multipliers, which the implementation if Fortran is quite sophisticated and extremely time consuming.

Comment: What is ML?....

Comment: It is possible to call Python directly form other languages using the C interface. No, it is not simple. If you had something in C++ instead of Python, it would be *much* easier to call. Finally, note that the language is called Fortran, not FORTRAN, and has been for 30 years. And Abaqus does *not* require Fortran 77.

Comment: Thank you @VladimirF. While there are some C++ modules for machine learning, my concern regarding the performance remains since the main issue is the prompt call itself. I have been able to call the python script, the matter is that it is performed over and over again. Wouldn't it be a problem for a C++ script just as well?

Comment: No, you would have to call the C++ function directly from Fortran, no prompt at all.