# How to call Python in ABAQUS UMAT subroutine

Tags: python, fortran, abaqus

Recently I'm doing multiscale computation in ABAQUS, so I want to call microscale ABAQUS Python code in UMAT.

I have searched many codes, libraries(f2py, forpy) and documents but could not find a proper solution to embed the above ABAQUS Python code into UMAT.

Usually UMAT is written in Fortran, so the problem might be 'How to call Python in Fortran', but ABAQUS provide a modified python, so the expression should be modified as 'How to call ABAQUS Python in UMAT'.

I have tried system call as a test example.

```
SUBROUTINE UMAT(...)

sym_i = system('abaqus cae nogui=F:/abaqus_python/simple_test/with_py/test.py')

END SUBROUTINE
```

Below is test.py

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(11,20)
print(a)
```

Here is ABAQUS log file output

```
End Analysis Input File Processor
Begin Abaqus/Standard Analysis
2019/11/27 20:24:51
Run standard.exe

 ***WARNING: Interactive messaging has been requested for this analysis run, 
             but initialization of the messaging system has failed.  Therefore 
             no messages will be sent to Abaqus/CAE for this phase of the 
             analysis.
Intel(R) Parallel Studio XE 2013 SP1
Copyright (C) 1985-2013 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
Intel(R) Composer XE 2013 SP1 Update 1 (package 139)

[11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
Intel(R) Parallel Studio XE 2013 SP1
Copyright (C) 1985-2013 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
Intel(R) Composer XE 2013 SP1 Update 1 (package 139)
```

The Python did work, however, the result is apparently wrong that ABAQUS continues computing without waiting for the finish of Python scripts and the main problem is that **I want to transfer data between Python and Fortran at real time. But when I call Python in UMAT, Fortran code still goes down without controling Python scripts.**

In other words, while executing system call, Python console is triggered and running, nevertheless, **Fortran does not wait for Python and continue**. **They are concurrent rather than subsequent**.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972538/how-to-run-ml-withing-abaqus-material-subroutine). I do not understand this *"But when I call Python in UMAT, Fortran code still goes down without controling Python scripts."* What does it mean?

Comment: I don't believe your interpretation of what is happening is correct. You cannot judge execution order by the order of output in a log. The  `system` call blocks until the caller returns

Comment: If it is Pure Python (not the modified abaqus Python) you can use CFFI. https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html#usage The Python function than looks from the caller (your fortran subroutine) like a C-Function or just another compiled fortran library.

Answer (score 0):

Pause the python script and confirm that Abaqus is waiting for the return of the system call

```
import time
time.sleep(60)
```